# Python runtime_library_dirs doesn't work on Mac

Tags: python, macos, shared-libraries, distutils

I have a Python extension module that needs to link against some dynamic libraries at runtime, so I need to tell it where to look for them.  I'm doing this by specifying runtime_library_dirs in my setup.py.  This works fine on Linux, but seems to have no effect on Mac.  I get an ImportError when I try to import my module, and the only way I've found to make it go away is to add the library directory to DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH before starting python.  What do I need to do to make this work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I finally figured this out.  The solution has two parts.  First, setup.py needs to use extra_link_args to tell the linker to add a correct rpath to the compiled module:

```
if platform.system() == 'Darwin':
    extra_link_args.append('-Wl,-rpath,'+lib_path)
```

where lib_path is the directory where the libraries are installed.  Second, all of the libraries you're linking against *must* have install names that begin with "@rpath/".  For example, if a library is called "libFoo.dylib", its install name should be "@rpath/libFoo.dylib".  You can use "install_name_tool -id" to change the install name of a library.

Comment: Could you post your setup.py? I followed your addition to setup.py and after that I manually run "install_name_tool -id @rpath/libfoo.so myfile.so", but it doesn't seem to change anything...

Comment: Actually figured it out. In fact when you build the libraries that you are linking against, you can add -install_name @rpath/<library-name> to the linker. That way you don't have to change it later.

Comment: Indeed...testing this out for my own package I found that on mac, runtime_library_dirs just adds an extra -L flag to the linker command, which seems strange given that that's what library_dirs is supposed to do.  On Linux it modifies the rpath as it should.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell what libraries an extension links against with

```
otool -L pyext.so
```

I had a problem where an extension was linking to the wrong version of a library on my system.  In that case I used install_name_tool to change the path to the library directly.  For example,

```
install_name_tool -change /wrong/libfoo.dylib /right/libfoo.dylib pyext.so
```

Comment: install_name_tool -change did not work for me, but

`install_name_tool -id @rpath/libfoo.so /path/to/actual/libfoo/libfoo.so`

did the trick.