# Compiling C shared library with distutils' setup.py, when the library depends on a second shared library

Tags: python, c, ctypes, distutils

I'm on OSX, trying to compile a shared library in C with distutils' setup.py (to use in python using ctypes).  I'm new to distutils, but I'm having problems when the shared library I want to compile (libreboundx.so) depends on another shared library (librebound.so).  Explicitly, in modify_orbits_direct.c I have

```
#include "rebound.h"
```

rebound.h is in directory /Users/dt/rebound/src/, and all the functions in rebound.h are in the shared library librebound.so, which is in /Users/dt/rebound/.

The linking with cc would look like.

```
cc -fPIC -shared reboundx.o -L/Users/dt/rebound -lrebound -o libreboundx.so
```

**UPDATE**:  This situation looks exactly like the example at the end of Sec. 3 at https://docs.python.org/2/extending/building.html.  I've updated my setup.py to mimic that one:

```
libreboundxmodule = Extension('libreboundx',
                sources = [ 'src/reboundx.c',
                            'src/modify_orbits_direct.c'],  
                include_dirs = ['src', '/Users/dt/rebound/src'], 
                extra_compile_args=['-fstrict-aliasing', '-O3','-std=c99','-march=native', '-D_GNU_SOURCE', '-fPIC'],
                library_dirs=['/Users/dt/rebound'],
                libraries=['rebound'],
                                )
```

This installs fine when I run

```
pip install -e ./
```

Build output:

```
You are using pip version 7.0.3, however version 7.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Obtaining file:///Users/dtamayo/Documents/workspace/reboundx
Installing collected packages: reboundx
Running setup.py develop for reboundx
Successfully installed reboundx-1.0
```

but when I try

```
import reboundx
```

in Python, I get an OSError: dlopen(libreboundx.so, 10): Symbol not found: _reb_boundary_particle_is_in_box, which is a function in the other library (librebound.so), which doesn't even get called in the code for libreboundx.so.

If I link the shared library with the cc command above, everything works, and I can use the shared library libreboundx.so perfectly fine in C.  If I try to take the same libreboundx.so I compile with the cc command and stick it where setup.py would put it, then try to import reboundx in python, I instead get

```
OSError: dlopen(/Users/dtamayo/Documents/workspace/reboundx/reboundx/../libreboundx.so, 10): Library not loaded: librebound.so
```

Referenced from: /Users/dtamayo/Documents/workspace/reboundx/libreboundx.so
  Reason: image not found

Could this be like an rpath issue, where at runtime libreboundx.so doesn't know where to look for librebound.so?

Comment: The `libraries=['librebound']` looks suspicious. This should not contain the `lib`-prefix, but only `rebound`. You don't link with `-llibrebound` either, but `-lrebound`. Other than that, can you provide the build-output?

Comment: I've added it in the question.  I get the exact same behavior/output with 'librebound' or 'rebound' in libraries (which suggests something's wrong!).  Also, I tried adding 'rebound' in install_requires at the bottom.  This gives "Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): rebound in /Users/dtamayo/Documents/workspace/rebound (from reboundx==1.0)", but the same error when I import in Python.

Comment: On OS X, `otool -D` shows the `install_name` of a lib, and `install_name_tool -id` will change it. If you want a path relative to the loading module, use the `@loader_path` token. List dependencies using `otool -L`, and change them using `install_name_tool -change`. You can also set the `-rpath` dependency search path; this can use `@loader_path` for a relative path. The `Extension` class has an `rpath` parameter, but this class really isn't appropriate for building a generic shared module (especially on Windows, if that matters). You can call `ccompiler.new_compiler` to execute gcc directly.

Comment: Since you're requiring a compiler anyway, in the grand scheme of things, your life may be simpler if you switch to using the API interface of [CFFI](http://cffi.readthedocs.org/en/latest) instead of ctypes.

Comment: BTW, I've never used OS X, so take my suggestions as a starting point. Refer to the [dyld man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html), the [OS X ABI Mach-O File Format Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/MachORuntime), and this article on [Mach-O Binaries](http://www.m4b.io/reverse/engineering/mach/binaries/2015/03/29/mach-binaries.html).

Comment: What is the output of `otool -l libreboundx.so`?

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for all the suggestions.  I should have specified in the question that in the end I want a solution that I could package for upload to PyPy so users can install with a single command.  It should also run on both OSX and Linux, so I preferred solutions not involving install_name_tool.

I haven't been able to test it, but I think adding

```
 runtime_library_dirs=['/Users/dt/rebound'],
```

next to library_dirs should fix the problem on Linux.  Apparently this doesn't work on Mac, but you instead can use extra_link_args.  Adding this below the libreboundxmodule definition posted above,

```
if platform.system() == 'Darwin':
    extra_link_args.append('-Wl,-rpath,'+'/Users/dtamayo/Documents/workspace/rebound')
```

fixed my problem.  I found the answer here:  [Python runtime_library_dirs doesn't work on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19123623/python-runtime-library-dirs-doesnt-work-on-mac)

Comment: this is not really gonna work if uploaded to PyPI. Unless the user happens to be called dtamayo and works from within a workspace under Documents ;) You will need to bundle the library with your package, and you will need to use an rpath that is relative, e.g. `@executable_path` or similar aliases.

Comment: That's right.  I wanted to try to separately locate where the rebound library was located, which seemed possible since python setup.py install lists it as part of its output.  I just couldn't get it to work before even when I knew the path

Comment: What I would suggest for experimenting: first, hand-craft the bundle you want. E.g. copy librebound.dylib besides libreboundx.dylib, and try & import the package. If that fails, use install_name_tool to change the rpath of libreboundx so that it *is* found (obviously using a relative path by using the @-aliases). Once you reached that, try massaging your setup.py until it builds/delivers this result.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying simple cases like that.  I found that the extra_link_args did what I needed with the rpath.  I'm now stuck on the next complication :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32313793/how-to-have-pypi-package-install-header-files-for-c-extension-with-distutils-set