# How to have PyPI package install header files for C extension with distutils/setuptools?

Tags: setuptools, distutils, pypi, python-c-extension

We have a package (rebound) up on PyPI that includes a C extension .  The relevant part of the setup.py file looks like this (simplified):

```
libreboundmodule = Extension('librebound',
                sources = [ 'src/rebound.c'],  
                include_dirs = ['src'],)
```

Additional libraries need access to rebound.h, but when one runs

```
pip install rebound
```

it doesn't install rebound.h anywhere.  How can we get distutils/setuptools to install rebound.h somewhere along with all the python modules?  We're hoping that we can have `pip install rebound` do all the work so the user doesn't have to run any additional commands.

Comment: Use data files / package data.