# Compiling and linking Python module in Mac Os

Tags: python, c, go

I am working on a Python module. I have C source file and a compiled library. I was having problems when linking in Mac Os, so I followed the instructions provided at [Python runtime_library_dirs doesn't work on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19123623/python-runtime-library-dirs-doesnt-work-on-mac).

This post says that add extra link arguments should be added when linking in Mac Os. It also says that install_name_tool should be used to change the install name of the library.

However, I am getting this error message when using install_name_tool:

```
string table not at the end of the file (can't be processed) in file:
```

The library is compiled from Go source.

Comment: Please include the exact command used to build the library (from Go source).

Comment: A reality check: to create a module for CPython, you're supposed to build your Go code in a way to provide a C-compatible "archive" or a library—that is, you're supposed to use the [`-buildmode`](https://golang.org/pkg/cmd/go/internal/help/) option with one of `c-archive` or `c-shared` values. The further build process (which would use that archive/library) is supposed to act in accordance with the type of the produced artefact.

Comment: This is the command to compile the library from Go:                              go build -buildmode=c-archive -o $(BUILDLIB_DIR)/mylib.a  $(LIB_FILES)

Comment: It works well on Linux. The problem is with Mac OS and setting the install name.

Comment: I have found something that may help me. Adding arguments to Go c compiler.

Comment: Then please answer your own question and then mark it as accepted. This is normal practice on SO.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't solved this problem yet.

Comment: Sorry. I just thought I had found the answer but I haven't. My idea is to add an argument to go builder like this: go build -gcflags="-install_name @rpath/mylib.a", but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

OK. This is what I previously had:

```
ext_modules = [Extension("_mypymod", ["mymod.c"],
                         extra_link_args=[],
                         depends=[],
                         libraries = [':mylib.a'],
                         library_dirs = [
                             lib_path
                         ],
                   )],
```

That didn't work in MacOS. This is how it should be:

```
ext_modules = [Extension("_mypymod", ["mymod.c"],
                             extra_link_args=[lib_path + '/mylib.a'], #full path to the library
                             depends=[],
                       )],
```

That works in linux and Mac.